# Permanently disable WiFi power management in Ubuntu Server 18.04

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, power-management

I have a small server set up that is connected to the network over wireless. I was able to configure wireless by installing wpa_supplicant and adding the required lines to netplan. I've been having issues with the server not responding right away to pings/ connection attempts after it has sat idle for a while. After installing wireless-tools I could see that iwconfig was reporting that power management was turned on.

As I understand it, I can disable it until the next reboot with

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off
```

How do I disable this permanently? I have tried creating an empty file called "wireless" in /etc/pm/sleep.d which didn't work. Other fixes I have seen for 16.04 reference /etc/NetworkManager which is not present on 18.04.2.

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: try adding the command to */etc/rc.local* so that it automatically gets executed at boot:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

iwconfig wlan0 power off   ### this line added

exit 0
```

Have tested this on 16.04. If you face any issue on 18.04 let us know.

Another way reported is to install TLP and disable wifi power management there: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/473753/45945

Comment: I had this need on 19.10 ubuntu and this appears to work fine at least over a couple days testing.